# How to create multiple jar files from a package?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have 24 .java files in one of my Packages...I'd like to create an executable jar file for each one of them, in one step...is this possible?

I have created a jar file from one .java file but surely there must be an easier way than doing this 24 times (once for each file)?

I want to be able to run my files from the command line vs inside the Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Why would you want/need to have several jars? It would be better to have a single class to be the main class in your jar, then when executing the jar this class will show options to call one of the classes inside.

Comment: I thought to execute one of my .java files it has to have its own .jar file?

Comment: No, it doesn't. That's the benefit of jars: they can package a group of classes, and the classes don't even need to be stored in the same package.

Comment: Hmmm...ok then...I can create one jar file but then how do I call one of the individual files inside it?

Comment: I think there might be some confusion with what I'm trying to do...my ,java files run as individual files and test one specific part of a website...so I run one file to create a record on the website and another file to edit that record. I have a testSuite file that calls both of these files in sequence so one creates the record and the other edits that same record. So, in my case, I (think) I want one jar file to create the record and one jar file to edit the record...so these would be called from the command line...

Comment: Why won't you just run the `.java` files?

Comment: @aldux You can't run `.java` files. Only `.class` files (or classes in jars).

Comment: You can specify wich class you want to run (must have a `main()` method) from the command line: `java -cp bar.jar Foo`

Comment: @RealSkeptic What I meant was why won't him compile his `.java` into their respective classes and run them one at a time? Why does he needs a `.jar` file at all?

Comment: @RealSkeptic that's exactly what I need to do...run them one at a time but I was trying to find an easier way to compile them into individual jar files...I'm inside Eclipse and can do them one at a time but there must be a better way to compile all 24 at one time? I tried from the command line using "javac -classpath C:\WDJarFiles\selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar TasksCreateAssignments.java" but got this error "TasksCreateAssignments.java:23: error: package org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel does not exist" -- if I can fix that then I can compile them from a .bat file to do all 24 of them...

Comment: And I'd like to add I don't mind having them all in one .jar file and calling each main section by their name as @Jaec pointed out...I don't know which is the best way to go or if it matters which method I use, as long as I can run each .java file by itself from the cmd line.